# how to extract string between two symbols

Tags: .net, regex

i have a string like this

```
*PMGFEC«                                                        
1.1GURRALA/KALPANA*ADT  2.1GURRALA/BHARGAVSRIRAM REDDY*ADT     
3.1GURRALA/TEJASVI REDDY*CNN                                   
1 DL  32T 30MAY Q ATLAMS HK3   745P 1040A  31MAY F             
                                           /DCDL*F9L4QB /E  
2 KL 871N 31MAY F AMSDEL HK3   150P  130A  01JUN J             
                                           /DCKL*7XZRBF /E  
3 AI 560G 01JUN J DELHYD HK3   650A  850A /DCAI*YCH0F /E       
4 9W 452W 08AUG Q HYDBOM HK3   605P  735P /DC9W*PYZJQH /E      
5 DL  49T 09AUG F BOMAMS*HK3   110A  700A /DCDL*F9L4QB /E      
6 DL9390T 09AUG F AMSDFW*HK3  1045A  155P /DCDL*F9L4QB /E      
OPERATED BY KLM ROYAL DUTCH AIRLINES                            
7  OTH YY 09APR W GK1  NYC                                     
TKT/TIME LIMIT
```

I want PMGFEC from *PMGFEC« using regex how can i do that

at present I am using `\*\w{6}\«` but it fetch `*PMGFEC«`

also

i want to fetch 1568.41 between USD and last space how can i do that

```
NAME    PQ TYPE TKT DES              CREATED       TKT TTL      
 1.1     1                            14MAY USD   1568.41       
 2.1     1                            14MAY USD   1568.41       
 3.1     2  CNN CH25                  14MAY USD   1363.41
```

Comment: Must it be a regex? Won't `string.Split` do?

Comment: nope i want only regex

Comment: In that case, this is a duplicate. See also the list of questions to the right.

Comment: are the symbols and the match always at the start of the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a capturing group you can use [lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to match only the wanted part:

```
(?<=\*)\w{6}(?=\«)
```

Comment: i have one more issue i want to select some currency between USD and Space but when i use your regex it didn't work i use user regex like this (?<=\USD)\s{3}\d{1,4}\.\d{2}(?=\s) for this string                                                        NAME    PQ TYPE TKT DES              CREATED       TKT TTL      
 1.1     1                            14MAY USD   1568.41       
 2.1     1                            14MAY USD   1568.41       
 3.1     2  CNN CH25            14MAY USD   1363.41

Answer (score 2):

This should do it `[*]([a-zA-Z]{1,6})[«]`. You can substitute in additional characters which would bracket your desired text.

[image]

Comment: I'm curious, what did you use to generate that diagram?

Comment: @p.s.w.g Check out http://debuggex.com

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to remember that. Looks like a very good tool for explaining regular expressions. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [group](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx#grouping_constructs), indicated by `(...)`, to capture only the characters you are interested in. You can then inspect the `Groups` property of the result to extract that text.

For example:

```
var result = Regex.Matches(input, @"\*(\w{6})«")[0].Groups[1].Value; 
Console.WriteLine(result); // PMGFEC
```